# How can I use a QDateTime inside a Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4, qthread

I have a thread where I need to execute a heavy function.

First, I have a function that takes two `QDateTime` values from the GUI and convert them to UNIX timestamps. Secondly, the "heavy" function uses these values to perform a task.

Both functions `(function_task, time_converter_to_unix)` do not belong to any class, so as far as I know I can use them in the thread.

But not the parameters, since I cannot access the `QDateTime` values.

> *Error: AttributeError: 'TaskThread' object has no attribute 'startTime'*

How can I access the `QDateTime` and read the content from the thread? Thank you.

**EDIT:** Complete Code. You can find also the link to the GUI in the following link: [interface.ui](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1siYGyHag9Qio3PUGvUrGXi9vufKDzdvJ)

```
import sys
import datetime
import time

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

# Link to GUI
qtCreatorFile = "interface.ui"

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

def time_converter_to_unix(start_datetime, end_datetime):
    # Convert QTimeEdit to UNIX Timestamp (int, msec included), and then to float
    start_datetime_unix_int = start_datetime.toMSecsSinceEpoch ()
    start_datetime_unix = (float(start_datetime_unix_int) / 1000)

    end_datetime_unix_int = end_datetime.toMSecsSinceEpoch ()
    end_datetime_unix = (float(end_datetime_unix_int) / 1000)

    return start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix

def dummy_function(self, start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix): 
    # Dummy function, just to simulate a task 
    result = start_datetime_unix + end_datetime_unix 
    print result    

class Tool(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        # Setting-ip UI
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Button Action
        self.runButton.clicked.connect(self.onStart)

        # Progress Bar and Label. At the begining, the bar is at 0
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,100)
        self.resultLabel.setText("Waiting...")  

        #Thread
        self.myLongTask = TaskThread()
        self.myLongTask.taskFinished.connect(self.onFinished)        

    def onStart(self):      
        # Before running the thread, we set the progress bar in waiting mode
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,0)
        self.resultLabel.setText("In progress...")  

        print "Starting thread..."
        self.myLongTask.start()

    def onFinished(self):
        # Stop the pulsation when the thread has finished
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,1)
        self.progressBar.setValue(1)
        self.resultLabel.setText("Done")  

class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):  
    taskFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):  
        # First, we read the times from the QDateTime elements in the interface      
        print "Getting times..."
        start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix = time_converter_to_unix(self.startTime.dateTime(), self.endTime.dateTime())

        # Then, we put these values in my_function
        print "Executing function..."
        dummy_function(self, start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix) 

        # To finish, we execute onFinished.
        print "Finishing thread..."
        self.taskFinished.emit()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Tool()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you execute it along with the .ui, you will see, that once we click on "Run", the Progress bar stays in waiting mode, and the error commented above appears.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you don't have `startTime` attribute in your `TaskThread` class. The same way you don't have `endTime` attribute there. In the short fragment of code you posted there's no place where these attributes are set and given the error message, you don't set them elsewhere as well. Where do you intend to set these attributes to your class?

Comment: Sorry. I just wrote the complete code. As you can see, the QDateTime objects (startTime and endTime) are coming from a .ui.

Comment: Okay... So, your `Tool` class does or at least should have `startTime` and `endTime` attributes as it subclasses `Ui_MainWindow`. However, your `TaskThread` is a completely different class which does not have these attributes. But you are trying to use these attributes as if they belonged to `TaskThread` class in its `run` method. Hence the error you observe.

Comment: If you absolutely need to access `startTime` and `endTime` from `TaskThread's` `run` method, you either need to copy these attributes from `Tool` to `TaskThread` class (pass them as `TaskThread's` constructor arguments, for example) or simply copy a link to the whole `Tool` class into `TaskThread` (also pass it as a constructor argument).

Comment: Could you please provide a code, so I can interpret a little bit better the answer? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @A.Pinero show your .ui, What kind of widgets are they `startTime` and `endTime`?

Comment: @eyllanesc They are _QDateTimeEdit_ ([link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html)) and they show hh:min:ss:z. In the UI, I need to write manually a time in those widgets, and then retrieve/read the value to use it in the thread class, by using the method _dateTime()_.

Comment: @A.Pinero If you show a [mcve], and leave the mystery, it could help you. :)

Comment: @eyllanesc Done! Now you should be able to run the code. The Interface is in the Google Drive link. Please if you Need anything else tell me :)

Comment: @A.Pinero see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startTime` and `endTime` belong to the GUI, and not to the thread, that's why you get that error.

On the other hand it is advisable not to access the GUI from the other thread, it is best to obtain the values ​​before starting the thread and set it as property of the thread as shown below:

```
class Tool(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    ...       

    def onStart(self):      
        # Before running the thread, we set the progress bar in waiting mode
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,0)
        self.resultLabel.setText("In progress...")  
        self.myLongTask.start_dt = self.startTime.dateTime() # <----
        self.myLongTask.end_dt = self.endTime.dateTime()     # <----

        print "Starting thread..."
        self.myLongTask.start()

    ... 

class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):  
    ...

    def run(self):  
        # First, we read the times from the QDateTime elements in the interface      
        print "Getting times..."
        start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix = time_converter_to_unix(self.start_dt, self.end_dt) # <----

        # Then, we put these values in my_function
        print "Executing function..."
        dummy_function(self, start_datetime_unix, end_datetime_unix) 

        # To finish, we execute onFinished.
        print "Finishing thread..."
        self.taskFinished.emit()
```